# How do I check what percent of a polygon is colliding with another polygon in SFML?

Tags: c++, graphics, polygon, sfml

I have a grid made of squares and I have polygons that look like tetris elements that I am dragging on the grid with my mouse. I wanna make a snap-to-grid functionality but to do that I need to check where the element best fits by seeing what squares on the grid am I putting the element over the most.

So basically, I need a pixel-perfect collision that gives me the percent of collision (100% would be completely covering the other element) but these elements don't have pixels or texture as they are just polygons drawn by SFML.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: The answer would be: By using math. You're just rambling, maybe go and try it out and then comeback when you actually run into an issue.